# jQuery cookie vs. cookies.set && not setting expires / only session

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a simple jQuery function creating a cookie (and yes I am including the plugin), I can get the script to create a cookie using:

```
$.cookies.set('LastArticle',  $(this).attr("id"), { expires: 1 } );
```

But the created cookie (in multiple browsers) **is only a session cookie with no expire date.**

I tried just using the more simple:

```
$.cookie('TEST_COOKIE2', 2, {expires: 30});
```

Test page: http://www.armorama.com/test2.php

and that produces NO COOKIE at all. What is wrong?

Comment: For earlier query...Not by a code check (yet) if that's what you mean. I am looking in dev tools view in Chrome and IE. Both are showing either no cookie (for test2.php) or a session cookie with null expires value (for http://www.armorama.com/test.php which I didn't list above). Also I updated the jQuery verison to 1.8.2 thinking that might be the issue and no help. There is an obvious script error on my test2.php page: **Object function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)} has no method 'cookie'**

Comment: Make sure it's included before it's getting used. Include it just after jQuery itself to be safe. & if that's not working simply try to rename the plugin.. just a trick, works sometimes..

Comment: Using your demo page, my console is giving a `FAILED TO LOAD RESOURCE: Error 406` on the `jquery.cookie.js` file.  See:  http://www.armorama.com/javascript/jquery/plugins/jquery.cookie.js

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. fanfavorite's comments below got me sorted and it was just a simple matter of mixing up my plugins. :(

The test2 page is fixed and working now.

Comment: @Scorpio, please explain how renaming the plugin could possibly make any difference.  If it's a caching issue, there are better ways to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting "TypeError: $.cookie is not a function" error.  Try using the document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Your Code
});
```

Also, I think you are mixing up jQuery Cookie scripts.  The one you are using http://code.google.com/p/cookies/, does not set cookies this way.  You need to use the $.cookie.set as $.cookie is not a function.

The Expires option is expiresAt, so should be:

```
$.cookies.set('LastArticle',  $(this).attr("id"), { expiresAt: 1 } );
```

Comment: Yeah I had it that way before but stripped it out for simplicity sake. It still gives the same error. This is really baffling me. I admit this is my first foray into jQuery cookie setting though so I may be just making some bone-headed mistake.

Comment: Thanks this is most likely the issue. I am trying to add Klaus Hartl's  jQuery Cookie plugin but am having new 406 issues (which I read about earlier so at least know that is documented). :D

Comment: Renamed file (apparently jquery.cookie.js is reserved or something) and now with CORRECT plugin all working fine. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the plugin you're using actually has a `.cookie` method.

It has `.cookies`, but not `.cookie`.

There are a number of jQuery cookie plugins (quite a few people have written it, since it's fairly simple and an obvious omission from the jQuery core); maybe you're using a different plugin to the one you think you are?